# How to record Audio and Video at the same time into flv in Adobe air 2.0?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, video, mxml

How to record Audio and Video at the same time into flv in Adobe air 2.0 ? So that Video and Audio will be sinchronised?

Open Source libs and 
Blog aricales are wellcomed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can help with are a few links, but I haven't tried this to know how feasible it actually is:

1. Audio - Recording [record microphone to wav devnet article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/using_mic_api.html) or [devnet cookbook article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_SimpleAudioRecorder___Microphone_Access_API_AIR_2_-16746.html).
2. Audio - Compression - [MP3 Compression with Lame and AIR 2.0](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1142) or [MP3 encoder in Flash with Alchemy](http://blog.debit.nl/2009/03/mp3-encoder-in-flash-with-alchemy/)
3. Video - [SimpleFlvWriter.as](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/) is a bit outdated and only writes images, not audio, but might be handy to get started. Also have a look at the [FLV Specs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flv/pdf/video_file_format_spec_v9.pdf).

At this point it looks like trouble waiting to happen:
Where do you store the images/sound until you write encode them ? in RAM ?
If you want to cache uncompressed files, will there be audio delays ?

It might be worth trying something different, like C++.
Or at least, write some command line tools for recording/encoding for performance
reasons and use AIR/native process just for the looks/interaction ?

HTH

Comment: Good for me pert - today I mor or less well understand FLV container format. So I can say that turning SimpleFlvWriter.as (which now can do stuff to only images) into something for Audio+ Video is quite simple (difference in FLV betwen audio and video "Tag"s is minimal). But steel doing it from Alchymy (probably encoding video into H264) looks interesting.

Comment: @Ole Jak sounds good. Would like to see your implementation when you're done. Goodluck!

Comment: Did it work? Were you able to save the video and audio into one file? Do you think this is possible on mobile AIR?